# Add app into left side menu bar on Frappe ERPNext

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I created a frappe bench and installed a new app named `Vehicle_Management`. I want to show this app module on the left side menu bar on my ERPNext. I am new to this framework. Please let me know how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an entry in the workspace, add shortcuts, and select the appropriate category. Once this entry is made you can see the modules on your home.

[image]

https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/desk#workspace

Comment: Thanx, It works. I just need to do something more. I can't add a 'car' icon for this. Will you give me some suggestions about it?

Comment: check `assets/frappe/icons/timeless/` folder for icons. you can use these icons defined in symbol-defs.svg file

Comment: You can also add your custom icons. https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/how-to-set-icon-to-a-custom-workspace-in-frappe-framework/76458/5?u=shridhar